# What are the manage tools for "One-Person UX Team"?

Tags: design-patterns, best-practice

Context: I am working as a UX, interaction and graphic designer on an enterprise web app. The team has never have a designer before and all design was done by developers and project managers who would only create simple sketches. I started to create UI style guidance and try to make the app looks consistent.

Question:
What are the best tool box to manage the UI style guidance as a solo designer?

Comment: Look up hallway testing, Joel on Software blog talks about it

Comment: Get a PhD in psychology first? Short of that, get management to give you authority with your responsibility.

Comment: I actually get fully support from the management team. I am wondering if there are any similar stories as solo designers.

Comment: This is still too broad a post. There is no single correct answer to a question that begins 'What are some...' - that is more suited to a discussion forum, whereas this site is explicitly a Question an Answer site - a question is posed and people will aim to provide *the* answer to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand your problem. I started as the only UX guy in the team and every project was just a fight and argument. Sometimes it becomes difficult to convince them why some things are right and wrong. Dev team is happy with the optimal performance so they don't see any need in adding any extra efforts. There is no hard a fast rule for everything. Propose what you think is right with proper cases and try to educate them.

You will manage. Keep reading articles on this site. Also understand Dev team has their own limitations so best practise is to understand their problem before giving solutions. This is not going to be difficult. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your thought. Yeah, every project seems a fight. I totally agree with you.  Address the problem before the solution is the method I am using right now. I am learning how to manage right now.